# Passing parameters using SQL to Webi report

Tags: business-objects, webi

I am using Webi to create reports but instead of using universes I would like to use custom SQL queries since I already have stored procedures created. In the stored procedures I have parameters like @date and @id. Is there a way to use them in Webi custom SQL scripts?

An example is:

```
SELECT
   Client,
   TradeSize 
FROM
   table1
WHERE Date = @Date
  AND id = @ID
```

Comment: What version of BusinessObjects are you on?

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to do this based on a universe and using custom SQL. If you are on BI 4.1 SP6 you can use Free Hand SQL. Here are some specifics on how to do that. https://blogs.sap.com/2015/06/08/web-intelligence-free-hand-sql-fhsqlstored-procedures-in-bi41-sp06/